# proot error: execve("/usr/bin/env"): Function not implemented from application shell in Android

Tags: android, linux, kotlin, ubuntu, adb

## Subject

I succeed in `proot` command from `adb shell`, but cannot execute `proot` commmand from application
I don't know why only `adb shell` scceeding.
And, I want to how to succeed in executing `proot` commmand in application, because I want to embed `ubuntu` to my android application.

Thank you.

##### command:

from adb shell

1. Put working directory contents from application
2. Execute android-ubuntu-gen.sh script

from application

1. Put working directory contents from application.
2. Deploy ubuntu-bionic-core-cloudimg-arm64-root.tar.gz
3. Execute bellow commmand from application.

```
chmod -R 777 working directory
```

4. Execute bellow script from application

```
sh start-ubuntu.sh
```

##### err message

```
proot error: execve("/usr/bin/env"): Function not implemented
proot info: possible causes:
  * the program is a script but its interpreter (eg. /bin/sh) was not found;
  * the program is an ELF but its interpreter (eg. ld-linux.so) was not found;
  * the program is a foreign binary but qemu was not specified;
  * qemu does not work correctly (if specified);
  * the loader was not found or doesn't work.
fatal error: see `proot-userland --help`.
proot error: can't chmod '/data/data/com.puutaro.commandclick/files/ubuntu-gen/tmp/proot-3044-1VKFuO': No such file or directory
```

##### about device

Android 8.1.0 (oreo)
torque g03 by kyocera

##### working directory:

- proot(directory)
- start-ubuntu.sh
- tmp (direcotyr)
- ubuntuARM64-fs(ubuntu directory)

##### proot direcotry(deploy bellow tar.gz )

https://github.com/green-green-avk/build-proot-android/blob/master/packages/proot-android-aarch64.tar.gz

##### ubuntu directory(bellow all directory):

- bin, boot, dev, etc, home, lib, media, mnt, opt, proc, root, run, sbin, srv, sys, tmp, usr, var

(deploy [ubuntu-bionic-core-cloudimg-arm64-root.tar.gz](https://partner-images.canonical.com/core/bionic/current/ubuntu-bionic-core-cloudimg-arm64-root.tar.gz))

##### start-ubuntu.sh (application or adb)

```
#!/bin/bash


gen_root_dir="/data/user/0/com.puutaro.commandclick/files/ubuntu-gen"
# (from adb) gen_root_dir="/data/local/temp/ubuntu-gen"

folder="ubuntuARM64-fs"
export ANDROID_ROOT=/system
cd "${gen_root_dir}"
proot_cmd="${gen_root_dir}/proot/bin/proot"

export PROOT_FORCE_FOREIGN_BINARY=1
export PROOT_TMPDIR=`pwd`/tmp
export PROOT_TMP_DIR=$PROOT_TMPDIR
export TZ="`getprop persist.sys.timezone`"
ubuntuDir="${gen_root_dir}/${folder}"
outpuDir="${ubuntuDir}/root"
rm "${outpuDir}/test.txt"
cp "${gen_root_dir}/startup.sh" ${gen_root_dir}/${folder}/root/

command="${proot_cmd}"
command+=" -0"
command+=" -r $folder"
if [ -n "$(ls -A binds)" ]; then
for f in binds/* ;do
. $f
done
fi

command+=" -b /dev"
command+=" -b /proc"
command+=" -b /system"
command+=" -b /sys -b /data"
command+=" -w /root"
command+=" /usr/bin/env -i"
command+=" HOME=/root"
command+=" PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
command+=" TERM=$TERM"
command+=" LANG=C.UTF-8"
command+=" apt list"


sh -c "$command"
```

##### android-ubuntu-gen.sh (adb only)

```
#!/bin/bash

folder=ubuntuARM64-fs
tarball="ubuntu.tar.gz"
gen_dir="/data/local/tmp/ubuntu-gen"
cd "${gen_dir}"

cur=`pwd`
mkdir -p "$folder"
cd "$folder"

proot_cmd="${gen_dir}/proot/bin/proot"
${gen_dir}/busybox2 tar -xvf ${cur}/${tarball} --exclude='dev'|| echo "decom some failure"
echo "decomp comp"
echo "fixing nameserver, otherwise it can't connect to the internet"
echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" > etc/resolv.conf
cd "$cur"
# fi
mkdir -p binds
bin=start-ubuntu.sh

echo "making $bin executable"
chmod +x $bin
echo "You can now launch Ubuntu with the ./${bin} script"
echo "exec ${bin}"
sh ./${bin}
```

##### application code

```
object UbuntuSetUp {

    private val genRootDir = "/data/user/0/com.puutaro.commandclick/files/ubuntu-gen"
    private val ubuntuRfs = "$genRootDir/ubuntuARM64-fs"
    private val startUbuntuShellPath = "${genRootDir}/start-ubuntu.sh"
    private val ubuntuTarGzPath = "${genRootDir}/ubuntu.tar.gz"


    fun set(
        cmdIndexFragment: CommandIndexFragment
    ){
        try {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                execSet(cmdIndexFragment)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception){
            Toast.makeText(
                cmdIndexFragment.context,
                e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
    }
    suspend fun execSet(
        cmdIndexFragment: CommandIndexFragment
    ) {
        val context = cmdIndexFragment.context
        val terminalViewModel: TerminalViewModel by cmdIndexFragment.activityViewModels()

        FileSystems.writeFile(
            UsePath.cmdclickMonitorDirPath,
            terminalViewModel.currentMonitorFileName,
            "${LocalDateTime.now()}\n"
        )
        FileSystems.removeDir(
            genRootDir
        )
        FileSystems.createDirs(
            genRootDir
        )

        FileSystems.copyDirectory(
            "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/cmdclick/AppDir/default/ubuntu-gen",
            genRootDir
        )
        FileSystems.createDirs(
            ubuntuRfs
        )
        val dirList = FileSystems.showDirList(genRootDir).joinToString("\n")
        val fileList = FileSystems.sortedFiles(genRootDir).joinToString("\n")
        val isGenShell = File(ubuntuGenShellPath).isFile
        val envs = Os.environ().toList().joinToString("\n")

        val err2 = LinuxCmd.exec(
            cmdIndexFragment,
            listOf(
                "chmod",
                "-R",
                "777",
                genRootDir
            ).joinToString("\t")
        )

        val monitorCon = ReadText(
            UsePath.cmdclickMonitorDirPath,
            terminalViewModel.currentMonitorFileName,
        ).readText()

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "start decompress",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
        decompressTarGz(
            ubuntuTarGzPath,
            ubuntuRfs
        )
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "start chmod",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
        val fileList2 = FileSystems.showDirList(
            ubuntuRfs
        ).joinToString("\n")
        val err3 = LinuxCmd.exec(
            cmdIndexFragment,
            listOf(
                "chmod",
                "-R",
                "777",
                ubuntuRfs
            ).joinToString("\t")
        )
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "start ubuntu",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
        val result = LinuxCmd.exec(
            cmdIndexFragment,
            listOf(
                "sh",
                startUbuntuShellPath,
            ).joinToString("\t")
        )
        FileSystems.writeFile(
            UsePath.cmdclickMonitorDirPath,
            terminalViewModel.currentMonitorFileName,
            "dirList: $dirList\n" +
                    "envs: $envs\n fileList: $fileList\nisGenShell: ${isGenShell}\nfileList2: ${fileList2}\nresult: ${result}---"
        )
    }


    private fun decompressTarGz(
        inputFilePath: String,
        outputDirPath: String) {
        File(outputDirPath).mkdirs()

        val outputTarFile =
            inputFilePath.substring(inputFilePath.lastIndexOf("/")).replace(".tar.gz", ".tar.tmp")
        var outputTarDir = if (outputDirPath.endsWith("/")) outputDirPath.substring(
            0,
            outputDirPath.lastIndexOf("/")
        ) else outputDirPath
        outputTarDir = outputTarDir.substring(0, outputTarDir.lastIndexOf("/"))
        val outputTarPath = "$outputTarDir/$outputTarFile"
        FileInputStream(inputFilePath).use { fis ->
            GzipCompressorInputStream(fis).use { archive ->
                FileOutputStream(outputTarPath).use { fos ->
                    var size = 0
                    val buf = ByteArray(1024)
                    while (archive.read(buf).also { size = it } > 0) {
                        fos.write(buf, 0, size)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        FileInputStream(outputTarPath).use { fis ->
            TarArchiveInputStream(fis).use { tais ->
                var entry: ArchiveEntry? = null
                while (tais.nextEntry.also { entry = it } != null) {
                    val file = File(outputDirPath + "/" + entry?.name)

                    if (entry?.isDirectory == true) {
                        file.mkdirs()
                        continue
                    }

                    if (file.parentFile?.exists() == false) {
                        file.parentFile?.mkdirs()
                    }
                    FileOutputStream(file).use { fos ->
                        BufferedOutputStream(fos).use { bos ->
                            // エントリの出力
                            val size = 0
                            val buf = ByteArray(1024)
                            while (tais.read(buf) > 0) {
                                bos.write(buf, 0, size)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

object LinuxCmd {
    fun exec(
        fragment: Fragment,
        cmdList: String
    ): String {
        try {
            val pb = ProcessBuilder().command(
                cmdList.split("\t")
            ).redirectErrorStream(true)
            val process = pb.start()
            val output = process.waitFor()

            var errContents = String()
            BufferedReader(
                InputStreamReader(
                    process.errorStream,
                    Charset.defaultCharset()
                )
            ).use { r ->
                var line: String?
                while (r.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                    errContents += "\n" + line
                }
            }
            var outputContents = String()
            BufferedReader(
                InputStreamReader(
                    process.inputStream,
                    Charset.defaultCharset()
                )
            ).use { r ->
                var line: String?
                while (r.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                    outputContents += "\n" + line
                }
            }
            return outputContents + "\n" + errContents
        } catch (e: Exception){
            Toast.makeText(
                fragment.context,
                e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            return e.toString()
        }
    }
```

I succeed in `proot` command from `adb shell`, but cannot execute `proot` commmand from application
I don't know why only `adb shell` scceeding.
And, I want to how to succeed in executing `proot` commmand in application, because I want to embed `ubuntu` to my android application.